# Ajax.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC not rendering javascript of target page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, navigation, actionlink

I have two divs, one containing a navigation menu and one the main body.

The navigation menu contains links that look like this:

```
<div class="LeftNavigationItem">@Ajax.ActionLink("Test", "SelectCity", "Location", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId="MainBody"})</div>
```

The target view returned by Location/SelectCity controller is rendered into MainBody but the javascript in it is not. Replacing the above ActionLink with Html.ActionLink fixes it.

For reference the SelectCity/Location returns a simple view with some  at the top and a bunch of HTML. Only the HTML makes it.

Is there a fix for this, or a better way to do navigation without refreshing the navigation static div?

Comment: Did you forget to link `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in your view?

Comment: Thanks but it's already there: <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>